# ApiController and IHttpActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net

I create an ASP.NET Web API based application and follow the tutorial from:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results.
[image]

I am trying to inherent `ApiController` class as descript in the tutorial and also to implement `IHttpActionResult` interface but the compiler complains, that the assemblies of them could not found.

My question, how to add assemblies for `ApiController` and `IHttpActionResult`?

**Update 1**

I add `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core` via nuget and it shows me error message 
[image]

**Update 2**
Error messages
[image]
[image]

Comment: What does the errors say? Are there any dependency errors? You might want to use a specific version of WebApi.Core. I use version 5.2.3 since it plays along with a lot of other dependencies.

Comment: Try adding `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    services.AddMvc();` in your startup file

Comment: This might be useful http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-web-api.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a tutorial for ASP.NET Web API 2, but the project template you've selected is for ASP.NET Core. These are two different beasts. To follow the tutorial, you should select the "Web API" template from the "ASP.NET 4.6.1" area, or [use a tutorial for ASP.NET Core](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-web-api.html).

ASP.NET Core ([previous called ASP.NET 5](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET5IsDeadIntroducingASPNETCore10AndNETCore10.aspx)) is designed for multi-platform development and runs with MVC6. There's a nice conceptual overview in the [official documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/conceptual-overview/aspnet.html). Here's a small snippet of it relevant to this question:

> With ASP.NET 5 we are making a number of architectural changes that
>   make the core web framework much leaner and more modular. ASP.NET 5 is
>   no longer based on System.Web.dll, but is instead based on a set of
>   granular and well factored NuGet packages allowing you to optimize
>   your app to have just what you need.

In Core, all controllers (including API controllers) inherit from the `Controller` base class. The assemblies you're trying to add are not supported in DNXCORE50 as they are not cross-platform.

Comment: What is the different between 4.6.1 and 5?

Comment: @zero_coding I've updated my answer with a little bit more information. ASP.NET Core is not a continuation of 4.6.1, it is a whole new framework.

Comment: So what should I use, ASP.NET 5 or 4.6.1? Which is future oriented?

Comment: @zero_coding That depends on your use case and your needs. Core is not [officially released yet](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap). 4.6.1 will be with us for a long time, but ASP.NET Core is the future for cross-platform and cloud-based development in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your usings:

```
using System.Web.Http;
```

Also, add this nuget-package:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core/

Run this in your package manager:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core
```

Or possibly this if you want a specific version:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core -version 5.2.3
```

It often adds this to your web.config:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```